# jsoup to check if a link exsists

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to check if a link exists, if does get the homepage.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
```

The issue with this is some times I get :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: X-MAC-ROMAN
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:86)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:469)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:147)
```

I got the related question answered by balu that:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(link).openStream(), "ISO-8859-1", link);
```

should be used when the char encoding is different.

But how can I get this working in a case I want to do page validation.

I will get link from user:

than I try

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
```

It gives exception when the char encoding is not default.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use `Jsoup.parse(...)` instead? This will throw an `UnknownHostException` if your link doesnt exist, else it will return your `Document`.

However you can use `connect()` in a try/catch block, if an `UnsupportedCharsetException` is thrown you can call the `parse()`-method in the catch block.